# Release and debug version of Dart build

Tags: intellij-idea, dart, dartium

I'm fresh Dart appretience and I'm trying the 'one-hour-codelab' tutorial. I'm using IntellijIDEA 14 and its Dart plugin.

When I build 'Debug', everything works OK in Dartium.

When I build 'Release', Dart code gets translated into Javascript, but HTML code is still referencing the Dart source file.

I assume there is some solution for this, do you know it?

Thanks
Rene

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source is meant to still point at the .dart files, since if the browser has a Dart VM in it, you want to use that rather than the generated JS. It's the job of the dart.js script (which is part of the browser package) to figure out if the browser you are running on has a Dart VM or not, and if not, to substitute in the appropriate JS scripts.

For example, the source of your index.html file might look like this:

```
<html><body>
    <script type="application/dart" src="main.dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
</body></html>
```

In browser with the Dart VM (like Dartium) the dev tools will show those same script tags.  However, in vanilla Chrome or another browser, the HTML you see in the dev tools will look like this:

```
<html><body>
    <script type="application/dart" src="http://localhost:8080/main.js">/script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
</body></html>
```

This is because the dart.js script has replaced the `main.dart` script with the corresponding JS file.

If you aren't seeing this translation happen, make sure that you are including the dart.js script in your index.html file, and that you are using the browser package by adding it to the dependencies of you pubspec.yaml file:

```
dependencies:
  browser: any
```

It's worth noting that the `--mode=release` option for the `pub build` command doesn't include the .dart files in its output, but other modes will (https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/cmd/pub-build.html). I suppose that since no browsers in the wild currently have a Dart VM in them, that `pub build` assumes you only want to release JS files. I suspect this might change if/when vanilla Chrome gets the Dart VM added in. In the meantime, after you build your project, if you want it to also work in Dartium, you'll need to add in the .dart files to the build output. If you wanted to get extra fancy, you could minify your Dart first by using dart2js with the `--output-type=dart` flag set (https://www.dartlang.org/tools/dart2js/#options).

Comment: In fact, in my Chrome both Debug and Release works and the source looks like the first one in your post. Also I found out that *.dart source is not present in the generated 'build' directory, so Dartium gets 404. But why Chrome doesn't get it? Confusing.

Comment: The source is going to look the same in both browsers, but the code the browser uses (open dev tools and look on the elements tab) should differ, with Chrome using a .js file instead of .dart (hence no 404 if the .dart is missing).

Comment: Yeah, understand now. But don't you know why it isn't in the build directory?

Comment: I think I found what was tripping you up. I've appended a paragraph to the end of the answer that hopefully will finish clearing it all up for you. Let me know if it helps.